# The scores for this site may not be accurate before running with sufficient live traffic

Tags: wordpress, recaptcha, contact-form-7, recaptcha-v3

Does anyone know how to resolve these errors I am seeing on my recaptcha analytics page?

[image: Note: The scores for this site may not be accurate before running with sufficient live traffic.]